# Using $window in http interceptor service

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use the $window object in an http interceptor so I can reference to the localStorage.

The problem is that whenever I remove the following line, my web app works. But when I add it, no page loads, just a white screen, but there are no errors either.

```
let {$window} = this;
```

My main module **config**:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');
```

My **authInterceptor** service class:

```
export class authInterceptor {
  constructor($window) {
    this.$window = $window;
  }

  request(config) {
    let {$window} = this;

    return config;
  }

  responseError(response) {
    return response;
  }

}
authInterceptor.$inject = ['$window'];
```

Comment: Then don't use it? Just use this.$window? Or just use let w = this.$window? My guess is that your transpiler doesn't support that syntax.

Comment: That doesn't work either, and this syntax works in my other modules.

Comment: Loggin the $window object in the constructor gives a valid window object btw.. hmm

Comment: I see that the problem is that "this" is undefined in the request function.

Comment: Implementing other services exactly the same gives me the proper "this" object. So my guess is that it has something to do with the Http interceptor. Do you have any guess how to solve this? @JBNizet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that ES6 is supported by the browser (and it's supported, since interceptor service is a class that is likely being transpiled), the only possibility when `let {$window} = this` can cause a problem is that `this` isn't class instance or even an object.

Interceptor functions are functions that are used as callbacks and [pushed to the stack](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.5/src/ng/http.js#L976-L984). This means that `this` will be `undefined` in strict mode inside them.

As any other class methods that are used as callbacks, these ones should be bound to proper context in order to keep it and be able to use injected services:

```
  constructor($window) {
    this.$window = $window;
    this.request = this.request.bind(this);
    this.responseError = this.responseError.bind(this);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for.